# Is there an easy way to input interlinear morphemic gloss in a normal document on an iPad?

Tags: interlinear-gloss

Similar to tools which help you type and format mathematics, or easy ways to type IPA, but for a nicely formatted interlinear morphemic gloss. Not in a Latex document, but a tool which helps you easily produce such text inside any normal document, for example, an Apple Notes document. Specifically, I am looking for such a tool on an iPad. You might think that this is a better question for Ask Different, but I think linguists would know more about it.